# How can we dynamically run different start scripts per local environment in React?

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, package.json

As part of our development environment we've chosen to launch React on port 3006, rather than the usual port of 3000.

On a Mac, you can achieve this by adding the following to package.json.

```js
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=3006 react-scripts start",
```

But on Windows, you have to add the following instead.

```js
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start",
```

As we have developers working with both machines (Mac and Windows), is there a good way to handle the different start scripts on each machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of cross-env package by installing it as a dev dependency like

```
npm install -S cross-env
```

or

```
yarn add -D cross-env
```

and then you can simply write your command in package.json as below

```
"scripts": {
    "start": " cross-env PORT=3006 react-scripts start",
}
```

Now this will work on Windows, linux or even Mac based systems

Answer (score 1):

One method is doing it like this:

```
"scripts" : {
    "start-windows" : "PORT=3006 react-scripts start",
    "start-mac" : "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start"
}
```

Comment: Interesting. And then we’d just call `yarn start-mac` or `yarn start-windows` to launch the project on each operating system

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration).

Basically just add `.env` file in root of your project and add

```
PORT=3006
```

Of course this can handle e.g. PORT and other configuration specified in the link, if you need something other than that you'll need to use something like [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env).